# Can a hostless XCTest target gather code coverage data?

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, gcov

I have an iOS app in Xcode 8.2. It has a test target / scheme, for which “Gather coverage data” is checked in the scheme’s Test / Info settings. Coverage data is not gathered. I see how many times a line was iterated over in the gutter as usual, but the Report navigator’s test runs don’t indicate any coverage at all.

I’m wondering if this is because I’ve set the tests to run hostless, i.e. without needing to actually  fire up my app – they’re pure logic tests.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a hostless XCTest target should gather code coverage data.

'iOS Unit Testing' (aka XCTest) bundles, which test a dynamic framework or something else which doesn't require the application environment to exist  to run, should happily collect code coverage data and display it in Xcode. Even of the Host Application is set to None. This works either when running Xcode > Product > Test on the Scheme for the framework under test or on the Scheme for the unit tests themselves (if the test bundle is listed in the Test pane of the Scheme editor).

Your problem must be somewhere else, sorry. Its hard for me to guess what the problem is, I suggest you try making a fresh project and see if you can reproduce the problem.